# DOH test with ajax post

Tags: javascript, dojo, doh

I have this test in DOH:

```
 name: "refreshNotification_NotNullData", //refreshNotification action tesztje, nem adhat vissza null-t
          runTest: function(){   
              require(["webnyk/common/components/ajaxAction"], function(ajaxAction){
                      ajaxAction.post({
                            actionName: "refreshNotification",
                            callback: function(_response){                      
                                 doh.assertNotEqual(null, _response.data);

                            }
                      });
              });
          }
```

When i run the test it gives the following error:

```
 Error: token is not defined
     ERROR IN:
         function (){   
              require(["webnyk/common/components/ajaxAction"], function(ajaxAction){
                      ajaxAction.post({
                            actionName: "refreshNotification",
                            callback: function(_response){                      
                                 doh.assertNotEqual(null, _response.data);

                            }
                      });
              });
          }
 FAILED test: refreshNotification_NotNullData 17 ms
```

This is a working call from my webapp.
What i am doing wrong?

Comment: What does the `_response.data` contain?

Comment: There is a Json string.

Comment: Okay, i found the solution, i missed the token.